# How do I declare a variable in @body for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, variables, html-email

I am trying to send an email through SQL Server. Everything is working however I can not get the `@body` to accept the variables I am declaring.

I also tried calling a new variable and setting that to the `@body` but I am running into the same issue.

```
Declare @Body varchar(max),    
      @TableHead varchar(max),
      @TableTail varchar(max),
      @message as varchar(max)     

Set @message=
    (

    DECLARE @CNT as int, @SLS as NVARCHAR(10)
    select  [employeeid], [Sales]
    into #loctempemployee from tblEmployees  

    Set @CNT =  (Select COUNT (Distinct EmployeeID) from #loctempemployee)

    SELECT tr.Principal As [TD], tr.[Company Name] As [TD], ai.[Action Item] As [TD], ai.Owners As [TD], ai.[Due Date] As [TD], ai.Updated As [TD]
    FROM [tblActionItem] ai
    INNER JOIN tblTripReport tr ON ai.TripReportID = tr.tripreportID
    INNER JOIN tblCustomers cu ON cu.CustomerID = tr.[Customer ID]
    INNER JOIN tblEmployees em ON em.EmployeeID = cu.EmployeeID
    WHERE em.Sales = (Select sales from #loctempemployee Where EmployeeID = (Select top 1 EmployeeID from #loctempemployee))
    For XML raw('tr'), Elements

    Delete #loctempemployee Where EmployeeID = (Select top 1 EmployeeID from #loctempemployee) 
    set @CNT = @CNT -1;

    End

    drop table #loctempemployee 
)

Select @Body = (@message)
```

Comment: `Everything is working` - I find that hard to believe. This code makes no sense and will not compile. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @squillman it is saying there is incorrect syntax with the declare line. I read somewhere that you can't declare variables in the body of an email for sql server

Comment: @GSerg when I say everything is working, when I run each portion of the code separately it runs fine and returns the results I am looking for. But when I combine it all together and try to put it in an email format, it won't compile. I didn't add everything sine all the other code is running fine.

Comment: You can't set a variable to be a T-SQL statement (unless you encapsulate that statement in quotes, but the  it's just a string). What are you trying to actually achieve here? Dynamic SQL?

Comment: There is no chance this works. That whole bit where you set @message is a total train wreck. That is not how t-sql works at all. You can't set a variable to a whole block of code.

Comment: `I read somewhere` - could it have been the [documentation for `sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? While it is correct that you may not refer to locally declared variables from inside the query that you pass for `@query`, you are not even trying to do that. You are trying to assign a block of commands to a local variable which makes no sense regardless of dbmail.

Comment: So originally I had a select statement as the @body of them email and the code runs and compiles. But then I wanted to add some logic within one of the fields in the select statement where it will create a temp table and loop through that temp table row by row and replace that field from the temp table field. Is there any way I can combine logic and a select statement into the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to assign the result of the `SELECT` to `@message`.  The syntax you are using is not correct.  You can't run a batch of statements within a `SET` like that in TSQL.  You can assign `@message` the results of a query so long as your query produces a string result.  So I think you probably want to change your code to be something like this (pulling the other statements out of your `SET` statement).

```
Declare @Body varchar(max),    
      @TableHead varchar(max),
      @TableTail varchar(max),
      @message as varchar(max);     


    DECLARE @CNT as int, @SLS as NVARCHAR(10);
    select  [employeeid], [Sales]
    into #loctempemployee from tblEmployees;  

    Set @CNT =  (Select COUNT (Distinct EmployeeID) from #loctempemployee);

Set @message=
    (
    SELECT tr.Principal As [TD], tr.[Company Name] As [TD], ai.[Action Item] As [TD], ai.Owners As [TD], ai.[Due Date] As [TD], ai.Updated As [TD]
    FROM [tblActionItem] ai
    INNER JOIN tblTripReport tr ON ai.TripReportID = tr.tripreportID
    INNER JOIN tblCustomers cu ON cu.CustomerID = tr.[Customer ID]
    INNER JOIN tblEmployees em ON em.EmployeeID = cu.EmployeeID
    WHERE em.Sales = (Select sales from #loctempemployee Where EmployeeID = (Select top 1 EmployeeID from #loctempemployee))
    For XML raw('tr'), Elements
    );


Delete #loctempemployee Where EmployeeID = (Select top 1 EmployeeID from #loctempemployee); 
    set @CNT = @CNT -1;

drop table #loctempemployee; 

Select @Body = (@message);
```

Also, are you doing this in a loop that you're not showing?  There is an `END` that does not have a corresponding `BEGIN`, and that would also explain the line `set @CNT = @CNT -1;`.

Answer (score 1):

the comments are quite correct - you cannot execute a huge block of SQL in a variable assignment to a single data type.

If you get the data you want into a #temp table you can use something like the following.

```
    DECLARE @xml VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT [col1] AS 'td','',[col2] AS 'td','', [col3] AS 'td'
    FROM #temptable 
    FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

    SET @body ='<html><body><H3>(Report Title)</H3>
    <table border = 1> 
    <tr>
    <th> Col1 </th> <th> Col2 </th> <th> Col3 </th>'    

    SET @body = @body + @xml + '</table></body></html>'

    -- mail out contents 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @emailaddress,
                                    @body = @body,
                                    @body_format = 'HTML',
                                    @subject = 'SomeReport',
                                    @profile_name = 'SomeProfileName';
```